# If statements and JOptionPane

Tags: if-statement, joptionpane

The program is suppose to have the user enter 3 sides using JOptionPane and then tell them what type of triangle it is and to calculate the area using JOptionPane.

I had the program working, but then I realized i needed to add the first if statement i have where if a,b or c is greater than the sum of the other 2 sides then it will print there is no triangle.

My problem is that when the first if statement is true than it works. But if it is not true it tells me there is no triangle and ends the program without going to the rest of the if statements.

```
 package assignment.ii;
 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import java.lang.*;
 public class AssignmentII

    {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int a = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a side of the triangle "));
    int b = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a side of the triangle "));
    int c = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a side of the triangle "));
    double s = (.5*(a+b+c));
    {
    if (a>=b+c || b>=a+c || c>=a+b); {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no triangle");
               System.exit(0); }

    }if ((a==b) && (b==c)) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The triangle is a equilateral triangle");

    }else if (((a*a)+(b*b)) == (c*c)) { 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The triangle is a right triangle");
               if (a==b || b==c || c==a)
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The triangle is a Isosceles triangle");

    }else if (((a*a)+(b*b))<(c*c)){    
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The triangle is an obtuse triangle");
                if (a==b || b==c || c==a)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The triangle is a Isosceles triangle");

    }else if (((a*a)+(b*b))>(c*c)){             
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The triangle is an acute triangle");
                if (a==b || b==c || c==a)
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The triangle is a Isosceles triangle");

    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The area of the triangle is: " + Math.sqrt((s)*(s - a)*(s - b)*(s - c)));

    } 
  }
```

Comment: if-statements not working... indentation not helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an erroneous semi-colon that terminates that if statement.

```
if (a>=b+c || b>=a+c || c>=a+b); {
```

SHOULD BE

```
if (a>=b+c || b>=a+c || c>=a+b) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "There is no triangle");
               System.exit(0); }
```